# How do I replace UIPageControl dots with UILabel to display number of pages

Tags: swift, swift3, uilabel, uipagecontrol

I want to replace the dots of UIPageControl with UILabel to display a text like `page 1 of 30` in swift language.

Comment: remove page controller and set label at this position

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `UIPageControl` with a `UILabel`, and then instead of:

```
pageControl.currentPage = self.currentPage
pageControl.numberOfPages = self.totalPages
```

Set up your label and then use simple string interpolation:

```
label.text = "Page \(self.currentPage) of \(self.totalPages)"
```

Comment: How can I put it in UIPageViewController?